# How to delete a image file from external storage automatically?

Tags: android, delete-file

I'm trying to figure out a way to delete images from the external storage automatically.

In my app, the user takes photos for some purposes which are saved in a folder created by the app inside the Pictures folder. After some time, the photos taken are of no use anymore. Therefore, I'm trying to write some code that enables the app to delete these photos by itself.

Before you ask, I'm aware that is not normal for an app to delete files from the app without any command from the user. But my app is used inside the company, only by employees etc.

I'm using `ctx.contentResolver.delete(uri, null, null)` to delete the image file. I have a catch to recover the `SecurityException` like this:

```
   catch (e: SecurityException) {
      val intentSender = when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R -> {
            MediaStore.createDeleteR`your text`equest(ctx.contentResolver,         listOf(uri)).intentSender
        }
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q -> {
            val recoverableSecurityException = e as? RecoverableSecurityException
            recoverableSecurityException?.userAction?.actionIntent?.intentSender
        }
        else -> null
    }
    intentSender?.let { sender ->
        intentSenderLauncher.launch(
            IntentSenderRequest.Builder(sender).build()
        )
    }
}
```

And everything seems to work fine at a first look as the intent to accept appears -- but no image is shown and nothing gets deleted.

Am I doing something wrong? What could be a way to delete these files?

Comment: You should have started your post telling how you created the images as it depends on the used method how to delete them.

Comment: You confuse not involving the user with automatically.